# Mount encrypted volume in Debian

Tags: lvm, fstab, disk-encryption, luks

I was given a HDD that was encrypted using dm-crypt and I'd like to mount it as /disk2 preferably having the decryption password stored in a file, so I won't have to enter the passphrase when booting, but it's not that important.

When I try to open the disk in the file manager providing the encryption passsword, I get this error

```
Failed to mount "500 GB LVM2 Physical Volume".
Not a mountable file system.
```

lvdisplay gives

```
LV Path /dev/disk2/disk2
LV Name disk2
VG Name disk2
LV Status              NOT available
```

ls /dev/mapper gives the following, while the desired result should be disk2-disk2 I guess

```
udisks-luks-uuid-.....-uid1000
```

dmsetup ls --tree returns

```
udisks-luks-uuid-.....-uid1000 (253:7)
└─ (8:17)
```

lvs returns

```
disk2 disk2 -wi----- 465,75g
```

lsblk (before decryption) returns

```
sdb                       8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 465,8G  0 part
```

lsblk returns

```
sdb                       8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 465,8G  0 part
  └─udisks-luks-uuid-.....-uid1000 (dm-7) 253:7    0 465,8G  0 crypt
```

mount /dev/mapper/disk2 /mnt returns

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

fdisk -l /dev/sdb returns

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdb1   1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: What exactly did you do to decrypt the disk: did you use a GUI (which one) or a command line? What is the output of `dmsetup ls --tree` and `lvs`?

Comment: I opened it on Xfce desktop, the same can be done in Thunar.

`dmsetup ls --tree`:`udisks-luks-uuid-....`

`lvs`:`disk2 disk2 -wi----- 465,75g`

Comment: Edit your question, this information isn't readable in a comment due to the lack of newlines. And please report the information more faithfully, the way you're anonymizing it loses information. E.g. leave `sda3` or whatever it is alone, and keep the volume group name, etc. From what you've posted, it seems that the volume is not encrypted, since the logical volume is not on a physical volume that's encrypted.

Comment: I have edited my question. If I don't provide the encryption password, then ls /dev/mapper, lvs, dmsetup ls --tree, lvdisplay don't show this disk at all, therefor it has to be encrypted.

Comment: This is the dialog displayed after clicking the desktop drive icon http://oi60.tinypic.com/i1z3o6.jpg

Comment: You say that you want the disk encrypted, and to store the key in a file, for convenience (I paraphrased you a bit). This will make the encryption worthless, unless file is physical separated from encrypted disk, when not in use.

Comment: even if the file is stored on an encrypted SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence allowed me to access the data

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 disk2
modprobe dm-mod
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/disk2/disk2 /disk2
```

So I offer the reward to the one who'll tell me how to make this change permanent.

Comment: I'd like to know why this answer has already received -3.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember there are two layers of abstraction involved here. You don't "mount" an encrypted disk. You open the encrypted disk with `cryptsetup` (if you have the correct password). This will create a mapping of the de-crypted partition at `/dev/mapper/foo`. Then you can mount `/dev/mapper/foo` to your desired mountpoint (such as `/disk2`). These are two separate steps.

If `/dev/mapper/foo` is not formatted (i.e. ext4) then you cannot mount it.

To your other question, how do you automate the decrypting by using a key stored on your disk. Use the option `--key-file`, i.e:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 sdb1 --key-file /path/to/your/key
```

Answer (score 2):

To mount an encrypted drive you just have to identify your encrypted drive and partition (lets say it is sdb1).

Run the command

`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 EncHDD`

You will have to introduce your passphrase and a new device will be created under /dev/mapper called EncHDD. After that

`mount /dev/mapper/EncHDD /mnt`

and you will be ready to go.

Your problem is that your drive seems to be an LVM partitioned drive (run `fdisk -l /dev/yourdrive` to identify the partitioning scheme) if it was the only drive of the physical/logical volume you may be able to recreate it, if it was part of a physical volume grup and the other drives are missing you will never be able to recreate the volume group thus you will never be able to decrypt it.

[Here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm) you have a guide to LVM in case you may need it.

Comment: I added responses to your commands into my Q. BTW originally the disk was mounted as volume group disk2, partition disk2